# Session timeout, postback and page validation

Tags: asp.net, timeout, postback, validation

We have inherited an ASP.Net site with two search forms on it, one with validation, one without. Each form has its own button -and its own events.

When the page is left open (idle) for about 20 minutes and then submitted using the form **without** any validation, the page posts back but the events aren't fired. I know that the page is posting back because I've checked that Page.IsPostBack == true.

What's curious about this is that the Page Validators are fired (even though the button clicked has CausesValidation=false) and the page appears to just be refreshed. To me, the fact that it happens after 20 minutes makes me think it's tied into the session timeout and although I could just extend the session timeout (or create a keep-alive/ping system), I would have thought there's a more practical solution to this issue.

Has anyone else come across this issue before and if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Thinking about this further, one of the things this site does it pop the ViewState into session so I guess that's the root cause of it (I'm testing atm)

Answer (score 0):

Yep I was right, we implemented a quick fix to [move viewstate into session](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2009/04/17/Quick+ASPNet+Tip+Half+Your+Page+Size+In+ASPNet+Instantly.aspx) which is usually fine but because the session was timing out, ViewState was lost and then the events didn't know where to fire.